# Geometry nodes Bone controller

Tags: geometry-nodes

would love to control the isntances seperately by the bone controller, this controller is connected via a bone constraint "child off".

Now i want to instance this "Collection" on a plane (No difficulties doing that), But i want to transform the bone controller that i made seperatly using something like the proximedy distance, of one object to the bone object. E.x. When the "SPHERE" Comes close to the "Controller box", i want to rotate that specific "Controller box" with the bone includes, i added damped track to these bones so they "Wiggle" and actually want to delay that for every instance e.x. rotating the box. It's really hard for me to explain, but i hope i can be more specific with this screenshot

The reason i want to do this because i want to seperatly animate trees coming in that are deformed by the bone. Like a simple growing effect with a proximedy distance thingy, but that could just work i think with rotating and scaling the controllerbox of the bone

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope someone thats working more often in geometry nodes can help this boi out :)

Thanks!

Comment: I think that, for your ultimate goal, the simplest solution doesn't involve GN at all.  Instead, use bezier curves with soft body physics; use spline IK on your bone chains to follow the curves; move a force field object around to affect the physics.  If this meets your needs, but you don't know how to implement some of that, I can make a detailed answer.

Comment: @Nathan this will slow down the performance right? i can def give it a try, i'll come back later !

Comment: It should be fast in comparison to typical physics systems, because it's highly simplified and because there's no collision.  It will require caching/baking, but that'll be true of any GN solution that involves "...actually want to delay..."